# Laravel Relations: eager load model by its ID in pivot table

Tags: laravel-10, laravel-relations

I have database structure:

### test

test_id
name
...

### user

user_id
name
...

### test_result

result_id
score
...

### test_assignment

user_id
test_id
result_id

I have easy implementation of Many-to-Many relationship between user and test with test_assignment table as link table:

User.php:

```
public function assignedTests(): Relation
    {
         return $this-\>belongsToMany(Test::class, 'test_assigment', 'user_id', 'test_id')
             ->withPivot('result_id');
    }
```

Test.php:

```
public function users(): Relation
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'test_assigment', 'test_id', 'user_id')
            ->withPivot('result_id');
    }
```

I faced with the problem of loading the results of tests by 'result_id' in link table at the same time with loading assined tests for user.

I solved it by this way:

1. Added to test model relation with result:

```
public function results(): Relation
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Result::class, 'test_assigment', 'test_id', 'result_id');
    }
```

2. Use -> load() for already loaded collection of assigned tests with filtering pivot value ('user_id'):

```
     $tests = auth()->user()->assignedTests()->orderBy('result_id', 'asc')->get();

     $tests->load(['results' => function (BelongsToMany $belongsToMany) {
         $belongsToMany->wherePivot('user_id', auth()->user()->getAuthIdentifier());
     }]);
```

Then i use $tests[1]->results->first() to get the result of test (->first() because by default belongsToMany retrieve collection (bad)).

It doesn't seem like the best solution and i want to know if there is any proper way to solve this problem.